# Wrong JSON produced by JAXB annotations

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I am using `JAXB` to form the JSON response for my webservice responses.
The output JSON is incorrect even for simple classes like:

```
{"Product": {
  "description": {"$": "Queen size mattress"},
  "id": {"$": "1"},
  "name": {"$": "Mattress"},
  "price": {"$": "800"}
}}
```

My java class is like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Product")

public class Product {
    public int id;

    public String name;

    public String description;
    public int price;

}
```

Does someone have an idea of why "$" is output as a field name here?

Comment: JAXB (JSR-222) itself does not cover JSON conversion.  Some JAXB providers offer native JSON binding (i.e. MOXy), other times JAXB is leveraged with libraries such as StAXON or Jettison to produce JSON. Which are you using and which environment are you running in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what library you are using, but you can try Genson. It implements JAXB annotations that are relevant in JSON world and integrates quite easily with JAX-RS services. Note however that Genson is a Java/JSON lib, it does not handle XML.

To get started using it to ser/de your objects to JSON based on JAXB annotations have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/genson/wiki/JaxbBundle).